# Build error while deploying on Heroku my golang app

Tags: go, heroku, deployment, package

I'm trying to deploy my golang app on Heroku but I get this error:

```
-----> Running: go install -v -tags heroku -mod=vendor github.com/Burton-kun/app 
build github.com/Burton-kun/app: cannot load app/global: open /tmp/build_1971d8d9_/vendor/app/global: no such file or directory
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
 !     Push failed
```

I don't understand what's the matter with the packages. Does anybody know how to help me?

Comment: Try without `-mod=vendor` once? See if that works. File/ Directory doesn't seem to exists inside the vendor: `/tmp/build_1971d8d9_/vendor/app/global`

Comment: Ok I solved, instead of removing `-mod=vendor` I moved all the packages folders inside the folder: `vendor/app` of my heroku app and recompiled the go.mod file. Thank you so much to made me notice that.

Comment: Can you show us your `go.mod` file?